# How firebase download data (Usage) is computed?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, size

I have a firebase project where I am getting a lot of usage in terms of Firebase download data size. Its giving me approx 30GB a month while the data size is very small ~70-80MB in my real time database.

I am wondering how can I figure out if that is really the state of the system used. Is there a way I can see logs, traffic distribution and which nodes are particularly hit in my realtime database.

Is it possible to get a list of calls being to my database which downloads the data ? It may be a case that someone in my team actually is running a script to download data and playing around with it ?

Here is a snapshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: For self-analyzing what traffic happens when you run certain code, have a look at the tools introduced here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/profiling-your-realtime-database.html. If you think there's an abusive user, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) to see if they can dig something up.

Comment: @sachinjain024 Did you find solution to it?

Comment: @anusha Yeah profiler is a good help but the fact is I have too many nodes in my system and I cannot afford printing each and every node to console So I took the output to external file and generated csv out of it and run an analysis. Hope it helps

Comment: @sachinjain024 Thank you sachin. Can we know how many connections we have for our firebase through console?

Comment: @sachinjain024 one more thing sachin I can see Too_many_params error when I enter "firebase database:profile --raw". Do you have any idea on it?